# WatiN finding link to click issue

Tags: c#, html, .net, watin

I am attempting do some automated testing using WatiN and C#. There is a link on the page as an image with the html code

```
<TD height=27 vAlign=bottom align=right>
<A href="paymentdetailsupdate.do">
<IMG border=0 src="/images/update.gif" width=64 height=21></A></TD>
```

I just want to click the link but this is proving to be very challenging.
I have tried using following code

```
cloaspage.Element(Find.By("href", "paymentdetailsupdate.do"));
```

but it does not seem to work. It times out looking for the element. I have absolutely no idea why. I also can't edit the HTML to add an id or anything like that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I forgot to add in that I can find the link by going through the tables,tablerows, tablecells etc but this is very time consuming and not practical in case of html changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
Link link = cloaspage.Link(Find.ByUrl("paymentdetailsupdate.do"));
link.Click();
```

Probably the same result but you should give it a try...

Comment: Also make sure your element is not in a frame.  If it is the case, your variable cloaspage must be of type Frame, not Browser.

Comment: I get the same result. Its also not in a frame. That was my first guess. I honestly dont know why it doesnt find it but I went another route by using cloaspage.Links and searching the array for matching innerhtml to the href. I got it working in the end after hours of frustration.